# redirect to slave

Tags: redis, load-balancing, virtualhost

Does REDIS has built-in mechanism that will use slave when master is down?
Can I use virtual IP to direct to master and when Master is down is it possible to direct to slave?

As per the documentaion:

```
elect the slave to master using the SLAVEOF NO ONE command, and shut down your master.
```

But how the application will know about the changed IP?

mysql has a third party utility that is called MMM (master master replication with monitor). Is there such an utility for REDIS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a virtual IP in a load balancer, though this is not built in to Redis. Any quality hardware or software load balancer should be able to do it. For example you can use "[balance](http://www.inlab.de/balance.html)" or [HAProxy](http://haproxy.1wt.eu/) to front the VIP and use a script or rules that checks the status of Redis instances to see which is master and sets that as the destination in the load balancer (LB).

Going this route would require one or more additional servers (or VMs depending on your setup) but it would provide you with a configuration that has clients talking to a single IP and being clueless about which server they need to talk to on the back end. How you update the LB with which server to talk to is dependent on what LB you use. Fortunately, none of them would need to know or handle the Redis protocol; they are just balancing a port.

When I go this route I go with a Slave-VIP and a Master-VIP. The slave-VIP load balances across all Redis instances, whereas the Master-VIP only has the current master enabled. If your write load is very heavy you can leave the current master out of the Slave-VIP pool. Otherwise I would leave it in; that eliminates the need for failover updating of the Slave-VIP pool.